Why does Flutter Chrome debug mode `findProxy` not work
it just does not work when I use a proxy debugger on the network on Flutter Chrome.
But it works well on the iPhone debugger mode. It's so confusing.
enter image description here
I want the findProxy works well on chrome mode.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As we know, we can set the findProxy in the flutter config to proxy debugger the network. It works well on the iPhone simulator. but on the web, it does not work. this is
the problem. @NipulRathod thanks for your words.
